# Showing $(\lbrace 0 \rbrace,+,\cdot)$ is subring of $(R,+,\cdot)$.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $S=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Show that $(S,+,\cdot)$ subring of $(R,+,\cdot)$.

My attempt: (Edited)

I know that $S$ is trivial ring of $R$. But, I want to show it. Please correct my attempt below. Thanks in advanced.

(i). Let $s_1,s_2 \in S$. Because $S$ is closed under addition, then $(\forall s \in S).(-s \in S)$. Thus, $s_1+(-s_2)=s_1-s_2=0-0=0 \in S$. Hence, $S$ is closed under substraction.

(ii). Let $s_1,s_2 \in S$. Then, $s_1 \cdot s_2 = 0\cdot 0 = 0 \in S$. Hence, $S$ is closed under multiplication.

(iii). Because $(\forall s \in S).(s+0=s=0+s)$, then $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is the identity element in $S$.

(iv). Now $0\in S$. Because $(\forall s \in S).(-s\in S)$, then $s+(-s)=s-s=0\in S$. Hence, all element in $S$ have inverse.

(v). Let $s_1,s_2,s_3\in S$. Then,
$(s_1+s_2)\cdot s_3 = s_1 \cdot s_3 + s_2 \cdot s_3 = 0\cdot 0+0\cdot 0=0 \in S$ and
$s_1\cdot (s_2+s_3) = s_1 \cdot s_2 + s_1 \cdot s_3 = 0\cdot 0+0\cdot 0=0 \in S$

Hence, satisfied the left-right distributive.

If $R$ is trivial ring, $S$ is subring of $R$.

If $R$ is non-trivial ring, the identity element of $R$ under multiplication is $1$. But, $1\notin S$. Thus, $S$ not subring of $R$.

Hence, $(S,+,\cdot)$ is not subring of $(R,+,\cdot)$.

Any explanation to correct my mistake argument that easy to understand it?

Comment: That depends on your exact definition of subring in this context.  It is not uncommon to require that the multiplicative identity $1$ in the subring is also $1$ in the parent ring as well.  Under such a restriction, yours doesn't count.

Comment: Related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539538/is-the-trivial-ring-a-subring

Comment: I still confusing right now.

Comment: If $R$ is trivial ring, then $S$ is subring of $R$ right ?

Comment: So, if $R$ is non-trivial ring, $S$ is not subring of $R$ ? Since the identity element of $R$ under multiplication is $1$ and $1\notin S$ ?

Comment: Again... you need to share the definition *you* are using for subrings.  You labeled things (i), (ii), (iii) etc... however you are making a wild assumption that we have the same properties labeled the same way and we have the same list of properties as you do.  We are not mind readers.  We have not necessarily read the same books or definitions that you have.  There are multiple *different* definitions here to consider.  For some definitions it will be a subring.  For other definitions it isn't.  *How do* **you** *define a subring* is something that needs to be answered first.

Comment: I use the definition in the D.S Malik ebook: fundamental of abstract algebra.

Comment: You again assume that we have that book on our bookshelf or otherwise have access to that book.  Why do you assume that?  Share the *definition*, not the reference.

Comment: Definition. Let $R$ be a ring. A non-empty subset $S$ of $R$ is a subring of $R$ iff $x-y\in S$ and $xy\in S, \ \forall x,y \in S$.

Comment: Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring. Let $S$ be a subset of $R$. Then, $(S,+,\cdot)$ is called $\textbf{subring}$ of $(R,+,\cdot)$ if $(S,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ and $\forall x,y \in S, x\cdot y \in S$.

Comment: That's the definition and theorem about subring of a ring based on Fundamental of Abstract Algebra.

Comment: And, so, in *that* definition, does it mention anything about needing the multiplicative identity of $R$ to be the same multiplicative identity of $S$?  No?  Then why bring it up?  I brought it up originally because *other different* definitions bring it up and I wasn't sure if *your* definition brought it up... but now that you have shared *your* definition we see that it doesn't.  So...

Comment: Solved. ${}{}{}$